# React/TypeScript - react-grid-layout: onDrag is triggered when clicking the <div>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onclick, react-grid-layout

I am trying to build a grid with clickable and dragable itens using react-layout-grid component.
But when I click the item the drag is instantly activated without actually moving the cursor.

Can someone help me to achieve it? Here is my code:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="gridL" style={{minHeight: '65px'}}>
          <StarIcon style={{ position: 'absolute', fontSize: 26, marginTop: 20, marginLeft: '5px', color: 'orange'}} />
          {this.props.favoritesData == null || 
          this.props.favoritesData.length == 0 && 
          (
              <div style={{ position: 'absolute', marginLeft: '35px', marginTop: '24px', height: '30px', color: 'gray'}}>
                Comece a adicionar favoritos para facilitar o acesso aos seus sistemas. 
                <img alt="hehehe" width={10} src="https://rastreio.grupoleonora.com.br/favicon.ico" />
              </div>
          )}
          <ResponsiveReactGridLayout
              {...this.props}
              layouts={this.state.layouts}
              cols={{ xl: 22, lg: 20, md: 16, sm: 12, xs: 8, xxs: 6 }}
              breakpoints={{ xl: 1400, lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768, xs: 480, xxs: 0 }}
              rowHeight={50}
              isBounded={false}
              onDrag={this.onDrag}
              onDragStop={this.onDragStop}
              onLayoutChange={this.onLayoutChange}
              className="favorites-grid-layout"
              onBreakpointChange={this.onBreakpointChange}
              onDrop={this.onDrop}
              maxRows={1}
              verticalCompact={true}
              measureBeforeMount={false}
              isResizable={false}
              useCSSTransforms={true}
              compactType={"horizontal"}
              preventCollision={this.state.mounted}
              isDroppable={true}
              isDraggable={true}
              style={{ marginLeft: 25, minHeight: 55 }}
          >
            {Array.isArray(this.state.layouts[this.state.currentBreakpoint])
            ? this.generateDOM(this.state.layouts[this.state.currentBreakpoint])
            : null}
          </ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

and generateDOM:

```
generateDOM(layouts: any) 
  {
    return layouts.map((el: any) => {
      const moduleId = this.props.modulesData?.find(q => q.id.toString() === el.i)?.id || -1;
      const isContextMenuOpen = this.state.contextMenus?.find(c => c.index?.toString() === el.i)?.index !== undefined &&
        this.state.contextMenus?.find(c => c.index?.toString() === el.i)?.index !== null;

      return (
        <div
          key={el.i}
          data-grid={el}
          onClick={() => !this.state.isDragging && !isContextMenuOpen && this.openFavorite(this.props.modulesData?.find(q => q.id.toString() === el.i)?.url)}
          onContextMenu={(e: any) => this.handleContextMenu(this.props.modulesData?.find(q => q.id.toString() === el.i)?.id || -1, e)}
          style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
        >
          <CardLinkFavoriteDisabled
            image={this.props.modulesData?.find(q => q.id.toString() === el.i)?.imageNavigation.filename}
            title={this.props.modulesData?.find(q => q.id.toString() === el.i)?.name}
          />
          <Menu
            PaperProps={{
              sx: {
                boxShadow: '0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(58, 53, 65, 0.1) !important',
                backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(98deg, rgba(10,12,71,0.9), rgba(59,240,58,0.9) 160%)'
              },
            }}
            open={isContextMenuOpen}
            onClose={() => this.handleClose(moduleId)}
            anchorReference="anchorPosition"
            anchorPosition={
              this.props.modulesData?.find(q => q.id.toString() === el.i) !== null
                ? { top: this.state.contextMenus?.find(c => c.index === moduleId)?.mouseY || 0, left: this.state.contextMenus?.find(c => c.index === moduleId)?.mouseX || 0 }
                : undefined
            }
            elevation={0}
            componentsProps={{
              root: {
                onContextMenu: (e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  this.handleClose(moduleId);
                },
              },
            }}
          >
            <MenuItem style={{ fontSize: 12, height: 15, color: 'white' }} onClick={(e) => { this.RemoveFavorite(e, moduleId) }}>
              <DeleteIcon color="error" />
              Remover
            </MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
```

Problem: I cant click the div generated by generateDOM() because when I click it the drag function is activated and not the onClick event defined on the div.

Here is a live example of exactly the same problem I am facing (drag is activated onClick and not when moving):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-grid-layout-bug-dragstart?file=index.tsx

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the drag is instantly activated without actually moving the cursor you can add `onMouseUp` and `onMouseDown` events to set the `isDragging` state.

so that `onClick` event will be triggered if the item is not dragged.

by using this events you can track if the item is getting dragged or not.

If `isDragging` is 'true' item--> dragged.
If `isDragging` is 'false' consider it as regular click.

Hope this solves the problem!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand your point but, is there any way I can avoid onDragStart beeing triggered when clicking?